# How to add button class to button when on blur of text input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, onblur

I'm using ANGULARJS. I have a button that by default has a Bootstrap disabled class on it. I also have a text input. What I'd like to do is when a user enters something into a text input and tabs away or clicks away from the text input for the button to remove the disabled class on the button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) attribute, as follows

the 'disabled' class will be applied to if the vm.inputText is null and the 'enabled' class will be applied if the vm.inputText has any value. the vm.inputText should be bound to the textbox.

or you can use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and set it to a variable or function that has the login you need